# How to hide a navbar link option and only show the option when user is logged in in PHP?

Tags: php, html

is there a way I can hide a navbar link option and only show that option when the user has been logged in? For my case, I have a navbar consisting of Home, Contact, About Us, Services, and a login button. However, I want to hide the services option in the navbar and only display it when a user has logged in to the website and if the user is not logged in, the user will only be able to see Home, Contact, About Us, and the Login Button.

[Edit] Also, I want to know if it's possible to check if the user is logged in and then unhide the navbar option which in this case, the Services nav link? So I want it to always be hidden but only show the Services link when the user is logged in.

Thank you for taking the time to read and respond.

**This is the code for my Homepage**

```
<body class="hero-anime">
    <div class="ocean">
        <div class="wave"></div>
        <div class="wave"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation-wrap bg-light start-header start-style">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">

                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank">Rebux</a>

                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto py-4 py-md-0">
                                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4 active">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php" role="button">Home</a>
   
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="about_us.php">About Us</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Usage of Pin</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Locker Terminals</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chute</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">View Chute Content Level</a>        
                    
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                                    <a class="square_btn" href="chindex.php">Login</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**This is some of the code portions for retrieving the Login Details of User**

```
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    exit('Please fill both the username and password fields !');
}

 
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT user_id, password FROM Users WHERE user_id = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $stmt->store_result();
    





if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $password);
    $stmt->fetch();
    // Account exists, now we verify the password.
    // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
    
    // convert user input password into hash digit
    $userinput = hash("sha256", $_POST['password']);
    
     if ($userinput === $password) {
        // Verification success! User has logged-in!
        // Create sessions, so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        
        header('Location: index.php');
        
} else {
        // Incorrect password
        header('Location: chindex.php?error=Incorrect password');
    }
} else {
    // Incorrect username
    header('Location: chindex.php?error=Incorrect username ');
}

    $stmt->close();


}
?>
```

**This is the code portion for the Login Page**

```
<form action="chauthenticate.php" method="post">

<?php if (isset($_GET['error'])) { ?>

    <p class="error"><?php echo $_GET['error']; ?></p>

<?php } ?>

<label>User Name</label>

<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="UserName"><br>

<label>Password</label>

<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br> 

<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

Comment: Which PHP variables determine that you are logged in? You posted a bunch of HTML here, with no details on what code has been written on the PHP side, you may want to expand your question with any PHP that you have created thus far.

Comment: Use an `if` statement - if the user is logged in, allow the HTML to be rendered, otherwise, simply skip that part of the code, and allow the login button to be rendered instead.

Answer (score 1):

Before div container with navitems add `<?php if($_SESSION["login"]) { echo (here put your div, which you want to see if user has logged);} else {echo (another div);} ?>`  something like that :)